# How to convert geoJSON format from jsonp request to Open Layers 3 friendly format

Tags: jquery, jsonp, geojson, openlayers-3

I am using a jsonp request to a server which is returning a string containing the geometry of a multiline vector.  This looks like this (I've truncated it a little):

```
MULTILINESTRING((-0.61122 44.88987,-0.61108 44.88961,-0.6109 44.88926))
```

In Open Layers 3, when I usually create a vector feature I provide a string containing the geometry using the following code:

```
var vectorFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.MultiLineString([[-0.11151,21.24112],[-0.11151,81.24112]])
});
```

Notice the difference in the formatting of the strings.  Is there a way in Open Layers 3 of quickly reformatting the response from the jsonp request to allow me to quickly create a new vector feature based on this data, or am I going to have to parse the string and add the [] formatting myself?

**Edit:**

If I use the object returned from the JSONP request as an argument in MultiLineString directly (as follows):

```
var vectorFeature = new ol.Feature({
geometry: new ol.geom.MultiLineString(data.geometry)
});
```

then if I attempt to retrieve the co-ordinates of the object using:

```
console.log(vectorFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
```

I get Array[ Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]...  ]

Which isn't correct, and to me points towards the incorrect formatting of the supposedly geoJSON object?

**Edit 2**

The object being returned from the JSON request turned out to be WKT and not geoJSON which explains the difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, using a regex would be a good solution in this case:

```
var string = 'MULTILINESTRING((-0.61122 44.88987,-0.61108 44.88961,-0.6109 44.88926))',
    matches = string.match(/(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)+/g),
    results = [];

matches.forEach(function (match) {
    results.push(match.split(' '));
});
```

Returns `results` as a nested array object:

```
[
    ["-0.61122","44.88987"],
    ["-0.61108","44.88961"],
    ["-0.6109","44.88926"]
]
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mEjuaoPqWM0Zy6Y0RHER?p=preview

A sidenote, the string you get returned from the server isn't GeoJSON:

```
MULTILINESTRING((-0.61122 44.88987,-0.61108 44.88961,-0.6109 44.88926))
```

A proper GeoJSON MultiLineString geometry would look like this:

```
{
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0]],
        [[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0]]
    ]
}
```

Reference specification: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id6

Comment: Thank you, but the output needs to be a string, and the question really was whether I need to bother formatting the string, or whether there is an Open Layers 3 solution (which I'm surprised if there isn't).  Thank you though.

Comment: You're *not* passing a string here:  `new ol.geom.MultiLineString([[-0.11151,21.24112],[-0.11151,81.24112]])` You're passing an array object which contains arrays. If that would have been a string it would have been captured in single or double quotes like this: `new ol.geom.MultiLineString("[[-0.11151,21.24112],[-0.11151,81.24112]]")` That's a big difference. Open Layers doesn't accept a string as argument for `ol.geom.MultiLineString`. Check the API documentation: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/apidoc/ol.geom.MultiLineString.html

Comment: On this point though, the jsonp response I get from the server is a JSON object which I convert into a string (rather stupidly by the sounds of it).  If I have a JSON object called 'Data' how do I pass that to ol.geom.MultiLineString?

Comment: I see, yet again I thank you for your help.  This makes so much more sense to me now.

Comment: I've added some extra info on GeoJSON to my answer, because what you're getting as a response, isn't GeoJSON by far. Now on your object: If you're doing your JSONP correctly (the comments are too short to go in to that) the callback function for that request should return the array object you need to use with `ol.geom.MultiLineString`

Comment: I will amend my question to include what happens when I put the JSONP response object in as an argument in MultiLineString, it seems rather strange, and this is why the object was being converted into a string in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

The reply looks like [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) to me, isn’t it? OpenLayers have [support for it](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.format.WKT.html) directly.